# Finding Shortest Paths of weighted graph using stacks

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I will be given some kind of this graph as in the picture below. I've searched some algorithms but it seams as if it is something impossible for me to figure them out. In fact using [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) it is kinda of possible, but unfortunately I'm only allowed to use stacks (instead of matrices). I also looked for [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but I could not get the relationship with my problem.[image: picture]

Clearly my aim is to get all **shortest paths** from one point to another one. As I mentioned I will just output the solution from my **stack** in a vector string. I guess I have to visit each node and what I am most afraid is of getting stacked in a loop or even loosing the track during the search.
Also note that this is **not a directed graph**. If  Dijkstra's algorithm is applicable here I would be very grateful if anyone of you would guide me and I would really appreciate any help, suggestion, idea or even a vision for not getting stacked in a loop or loosing the track while searching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using stack you can easily explore all paths starting from a given node. You wont fall in a loop when you can remember those node already visited.

Comment: @MahmoudAlimohamadi .. put this comment as an answer. I think it should be the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

As with most graph searching algorithms, you have to keep the state of each node during the searching. The state would have following values: **white, gray, black** with following interpretation:

- **white** = node has not yet been discovered during the current search, or it is unreachable.
- **gray** = node that was discovered, but not yet processed by the search algorithm.
- **black** = reachable nodes in your graph, that the search algorithm has discovered and also processed.

This **labeling** ensures that you do not search in endless loops.

To get **all** shortest paths from a node **s** to another node **e**:

- mark all nodes nodes as **white**.
- then as you visit nodes you label them **gray** and put them on the stack.
- If you processed all neighbours of a node, you label it **black**.
- To recover all the shortest paths from s to e, you need to maintain an array, call it **parents**, i.e. parents(v) = u, meaning **v** was visited from **u**.

After you searched the whole graph, you proceed **backwards** from the end node **e** via the parents array, to get all the shortest paths from the starting node **s**.